# incrementing a form's input value (React Forms) with a button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, react-component, jsform

Once I click the button to increment, the input increments for a second, and then returns to its previous value

It's inside a form in a React component, I'm holding the input value in the component state

```
                <form className={style.createActivity} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                …
                <div className={style.inputDifficulty}>
                    <input className={this.state.difficultyError && style.danger} 
                        type="text" 
                        name="difficulty" 
                        value={this.state.difficulty} 
                        readOnly
                        />
                    <button name="difficulty" onClick={this.handleUpClick}>&#x2B06;</button>      // Up arrow
                    <button name="difficulty" onClick={this.handleDownClick}>&#x2B07;</button>>   // Down arrow
                </div>
                …
                <input className={style.submit} type="submit" name="" value="Submit"/>
            </form>
```

The click handles are

```
handleUpClick = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        ...this.state, 
        [e.target.name]: this.state[e.target.name] + 1
    })
}

handleDownClick = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        ...this.state, 
        [e.target.name]: this.state[e.target.name] - 1
    })
}
```

The state is:

```
    constructor() {
    super()
    this.state={
        name: '',
        difficulty: 1,
        duration: 1,
  …
    }
}
```

Why can’t I increment/decrement the input value with the button

Thanks in advance

Rafael

Comment: You can make a fiddle for the minimum reproduce case of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you suggested, the solution I suggested is this.

```
  e.preventDefault()
```

I think the button click form works together, so it prevents the spread of the event by putting the code above.
Therefore, resolve...

```
handleUpClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: this.state[e.target.name] + 1
    })
}

handleDownClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: this.state[e.target.name] - 1
    })
}
```

Also, it's okay if you don't put this. [`...this.state`]

I don't know if I can see it, but I'm sending you samples!
[sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-smoke-55vic?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)